# Canvas drawImage without using load event

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

As an introduction to canvas and the way they worked, I wanted to create a small quizz. Using only colors, I haven't any very strong problems that I can't solve by using google.

Now I want to show a background picture to the quizz but more precisely, I want that any question have a different picture as a background.

So I did this:

My main loop is a event binding on a function with click working like that:

```
qcm.canvas.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
        main(qcm, evt);
    }, false);
```

Then, my main loop will use values in qcm object to know what to draw. In any case, I'll clear my canvas and then drawing back the canvas skeletton (which at the moment contain only the background picture assignement).

This is my clear canvas function, using only a clearRect.

```
function clearCanvas(qcm)
{
    //Suppression du contenu du canvas
    qcm.context.clearRect(0, 0, qcm.canvas.scrollWidth, qcm.canvas.scrollHeight);
    // Rechargement du décor du canvas
    initCanvas(qcm);
}
```

the InitCanvas function which should draw the background is this one:

```
function initCanvas(qcm)
{
    //Background color
    //qcm.context.fillStyle = QcmConfiguration.Canvas_BackColor;
    //qcm.context.fillRect(0,0,qcm.canvas.scrollWidth, qcm.canvas.scrollHeight);
    if (qcm.backgroundImage != undefined)
    {
        var background = new Image();
        background.addEventListener('load', function()
        {
                qcm.context.drawImage(background, 0, 0, qcm.canvas.scrollWidth, qcm.canvas.scrollHeight);
        }, false);
        background.src = qcm.backgroundImage;
    }
}
```

When my canvas end "init" phase, it the draw the frame I want to show, (question, answer, score ... depending on the qcm status).

For example, here is a part of the main loop function:

```
clearCanvas(qcm);
log(QcmLogsType.Initialisation, "Chargement du start panel");
drawStartPanel(qcm);
```

Where my drawStartPanel is a function which just draw a "Play" button:

```
function drawStartPanel(qcm)
{
    // Dessin du rectangle colorée pour le bouton play
    qcm.context.fillStyle = QcmConfiguration.Start_BackButtonColor;
    qcm.context.fillRect((qcm.canvas.scrollWidth / 2) - 25, (qcm.canvas.scrollHeight / 2) - 25, 50, 50);
    // Dessin du triangle "play"
    qcm.context.fillStyle = QcmConfiguration.Start_ForeButtonColor;
    qcm.context.beginPath();
    qcm.context.moveTo((qcm.canvas.scrollWidth / 2) - 10, (qcm.canvas.scrollHeight / 2) - 10);
    qcm.context.lineTo((qcm.canvas.scrollWidth / 2) - 10, (qcm.canvas.scrollHeight / 2) + 10);
    qcm.context.lineTo((qcm.canvas.scrollWidth / 2) + 12, qcm.canvas.scrollHeight / 2);
    qcm.context.closePath();
    qcm.context.fill();
}
```

But when I execute my code, my start button seems to be "under" the picture, which mean that the picture load event seems to execute after the drawStartpanel function while the call is before...

This way I think that the main option is to put the picture as display:none in the html code and then draw it on the canvas, but I don't really like this idea, because I later want to try to do something which will go get pictures on a database, which will not allow to do something like that.

So I'm looking:

Either for a way to force the load event manually
Or a way to not use the load event to show my picture

(I didn't post the entire code as it's 800 lines but will if needed :) )

Comment: Can you share code on a jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: Just by curiosity, `qcm.canvas` is a HTMLCanvasElement right? Why do you use `scrollHeight` and `scrollWidth` properties instead of `width` and `height` ones? (I just learn myself that these props return weird values btw...`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply move your drawStartPanel function in the `load` callback like this :

```
function initCanvas(qcm, callback) {
    // Background color
    // qcm.context.fillStyle = QcmConfiguration.Canvas_BackColor;
    // qcm.context.fillRect(0,0,qcm.canvas.scrollWidth, qcm.canvas.scrollHeight);

    if (qcm.backgroundImage !== 'undefined') {
        var background = new window.Image();

        background.onload = function () {
            qcm.context.drawImage(background, 0, 0, qcm.canvas.scrollWidth, qcm.canvas.scrollHeight);
            // Here call the start button drawing function assuming it always takes the qcm object as an argument
            callback(qcm);
        }

        background.src = qcm.backgroundImage;
    }
}
```

Calling it like this :

```
clearCanvas(qcm);
log(QcmLogsType.Initialisation, "Chargement du start panel");
initCanvas(qcm, drawStartPanel);
```

**Going further**

Another way of getting the drawings synchronously applied is to use [Javascript Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: Your answer certainly works ! But, I use my InitCanvas each time I want to draw another "frame". Which mean that I'll not always use the same function, is there a way to pass a function as a parameter or do I have to edit the entire script conception ? (I'll post the entire code soon)

Comment: Yes, I edited my post so you can pass any callback function you want to draw after the background has been drawed. I hope this helps !

Comment: I'll have to edit a part of my script to adapt for this model but that should be good I think, I'll try and give you a feedback :)

Comment: So I tried to apply the first point, but I ended blocked on several points which would make really difficult to understand the code...I'll have a look on promises :/